# USB broadband 3G connecting to a wireless router

Tags: router, wifi, gateway, modem, 3g

In my workplace, the ADSL / internet line (which is connected to a TP-Link router) is **down**, so I need to use a USB 3G broadband modem to give other computers internet access.

I was wondering if there's a way to make the router use the broadband instead of the telephone cable, keeping in mind there's no USB port on the router.

***Note:*** We use the router as a default gateway for the domain computers, so it's easier to do this than using a broadband wireless router.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add another PC/laptop/raspberry pi/whatever to your network topology (or use an existing one), configure the 3G USB modem on it and point your router's default route/WAN-link to that machine?

Comment: I did not think of that .. will try .. thanks